# How to extract json, multiple value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hello I have a json data  like this

```
KLOBS   {"SL_VEF_APPLIED_VS_BOL_R1_KLOBS":["0.00247320692497939","0.000008129750823137272"]}
KL15    {"SL_VEF_APPLIED_VS_BOL_R1_KL15":["0.01890831252229754","0.9008162336184189"]}
```

I'm already try extract json

```
$.get('url_request.php?' + $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
    var obj = data;

    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
        console.log(key);
        console.log(value);
    });
});

$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(value);
});
```

And I get result

```
KLOBS 
{"SL_VEF_APPLIED_VS_BOL_R1_KLOBS":["0.00247320692497939","0.000008129750823137272"]}  

KL15
{"SL_VEF_APPLIED_VS_BOL_R1_KL15":["0.01890831252229754","0.9008162336184189"]}
```

I want to get result like this:-

```
KLOBS
0.00247320692497939
0.000008129750823137272

KL15
0.01890831252229754
0.9008162336184189
```

How to call `json` like this ??

I don't know call multiple value data in `Json`.

Please help me.

Comment: you will need to loop thru value array. something like value.forEach(x=>{console.log(x)})

Comment: can you try to remove serialize() from your request? if this is not possible you need to unserialize your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
    var arr = {
      KLOBS: {
        SL_VEF_APPLIED_VS_BOL_R1_KLOBS: [
          "0.00247320692497939",
          "0.000008129750823137272"
        ]
      },
      KL15: {
        SL_VEF_APPLIED_VS_BOL_R1_KL15: ["0.01890831252229754", "0.9008162336184189"]
      }
    };
    
    Object.keys(arr).forEach(function(key, value) {
      console.log(key);
      Object.keys(arr[key]).forEach(function(val) {
        arr[key][val].forEach(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: TypeError: arr[key][val].forEach is not a function  why ??  see my code. https://pastebin.com/WjBmg7fJ

Comment: log your `jsondata` please. is that exact the same as array you put in question? @MuhamadRidwansyah

Comment: try `JSON.parse` it. Think it is stringified.

Comment: first `jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonData)` and then `jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData)`. @MuhamadRidwansyah

Answer (score 1):

In general you could do the following:

```
var KLOBS = {"SL_VEF_APPLIED_VS_BOL_R1_KLOBS": 
["0.00247320692497939","0.000008129750823137272"]}

values = Object.keys(KLOBS).map(x=>{
    return KLOBS[x];
})

values.forEach(x=>x.forEach(y=>console.log(y)))
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) gives you an array of the keys in an object. 
Since I do not know the structure in advance, I assume it better thinking of more than one key.

With the function [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), a function is applied to each member of the array returned by `Object.keys`. This is used to extract the values.

The resulting structure is an array of arrays.

Therefore a double `forEach` is needed to display every entry of the structure.